# PHPExcel search/return all rows containing perticular value in cells

Tags: javascript, php, rows, phpexcel, cells

I tried to find a way to just get a particular rows using PHPExcel. After searching on the internet, I cannot figure it out on my own. What I want to do is to list all the rows that have a "I1/027" as a column content.

**For example:**

```
Hours | Place | Name
------|-------|-----------------
3     |I1/027 | example1   //------> Want to add it to my list!!!
6     |I2/025 | example2   //------> Ignore this
7     |I1/030 | example3
2     |I1/027 | example4   //------> Want to add it to my list!!!
```

Here's the code without the rows filter, it shows all the excel rows:

```
<?php if(isset($_FILES['file']['name'])) { ?>
   <!-- Container progress bar -->
    <div id="progress" style="width:500px;border:1px solid #ccc;"></div>
   <!-- progress info -->
    <div id="information" style="width"></div>

   <?php require_once 'reader/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
       //Extra functions
        function get_cell($cell, $objPHPExcel){
            //Cell selection
            $objCell = ($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cell));
            //taking cell value
            return $objCell->getvalue();
        }
        function pp(&$var){
            $var = chr(ord($var)+1);
            return true;
        }
    //==========Displaying Code
        $name     = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $tname    = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $type     = $_FILES['file']['type'];

        if($type == 'application/vnd.ms-excel')
        { // excel 97 extension
            $ext = 'xls';
        }
        else if($type == 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
        { // excel 2007 and 2010 extensions
            $ext = 'xlsx';
        }else
        { // invalid extension
            echo -1;
            exit();
        }
        $xlsx = 'Excel2007';
        $xls  = 'Excel5';

        //read creator
        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($$ext);
        //loading
        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($tname);

        $dim = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->calculateWorksheetDimension();
        // put $start and $end array
        list($start, $end) = explode(':', $dim);

        if(!preg_match('#([A-Z]+)([0-9]+)#', $start, $rslt)){
            return false;
        }
        list($start, $start_h, $start_v) = $rslt;
        if(!preg_match('#([A-Z]+)([0-9]+)#', $end, $rslt)){
            return false;
        }
        list($end, $end_h, $end_v) = $rslt;

        //starting to read excel doc
        $table = "<table class='tabla'>";
        for($v=$start_v; $v<=$end_v; $v++){     
            // calculate progress bar
            $percent = intval($v/$end_v * 100)."%";
            // progress bar update
            echo '<script language="javascript">
            document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML="<div style=\"width:'.$percent.';background-color:#ddd;\">&nbsp;'.$percent.'</div>";
            document.getElementById("information").innerHTML="'.$v.' files processades.";</script>'; 

            // buffer flush
            echo str_repeat(' ',1024*64);
            // send exit to navigator
            flush();
            sleep(0.25);

            //horizontal reading
            $table .= "<tr>";
            for($h=$start_h; ord($h)<=ord($end_h); pp($h)){
                $cellValue = get_cell($h.$v, $objPHPExcel);
                $table .= "<td>";
                if($cellValue !== null){
                    $table .= $cellValue;
                }
                $table .= "</td>";
            }
            $table .= "</tr>";
        }
        $table .= "</table>";

        // process completed
        echo '<script language="javascript">document.getElementById("information").innerHTML="Procés complet"</script><br>';
        echo $table;
    }?>
</div>
```

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: Sorry for the ugly table  @Adarsh Rajput, I didn't realize the disorder until now. Thanks a lot for the clean up!

Comment: No prob. friend, that's what for stackoverflow is... :) did my answer solved your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:** Here you just need to use simple logic. Change your horizontal reading code like following:

```
 //horizontal reading
 $tempRow= "<tr>";
 $contentFound=false;

 for($h=$start_h; ord($h)<=ord($end_h); pp($h)){
     $cellValue = get_cell($h.$v, $objPHPExcel);
     $tempRow.= "<td>";
     if($cellValue !== null){
         if($cellValue=="I1/027") $contentFound=true;
         $tempRow.= $cellValue;
     }
     $tempRow.= "</td>";
  }
  $tempRow.= "</tr>";

if($contentFound) $table.=$tempRow;
```

**Logic:** I just stored the row in to temp var and compared row's each cell value to desired content. If it matched then I set `$contentFound` to `ture`, and added temp row to main table (`$table` var). In next loop of vertical reading again `$tempRow and $contentFound` will set to original state, so finally desired rows will be in our output.

**Note:** As per my knowledge there is no inbuilt search function in PHPExcel.

Comment: You're correct, PHPExcel doesn't provide any built-in search function

Comment: @AdarshRajput, thank you again, your code worked like a charm!! I thought PHPExcel had It's own search function, this makes things awkward. You know if there are built-in functions to clean or discriminate repeated rows?

Thanks a lot to everyone!!